# Access google analytics data with Django

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, oauth2client

I'm trying to build a super simple dashboard to show to users their Google Analytics data well formatted.

I'm using [oAuth2Client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) and Django 1.10.4 and Python 3.5.

I've followed the example within the documentation and now I have a very simple app, the landing page will ask you to login, you click on a link to authorise, the Google page loads and asks you if you want to share your GA data and if you accept you are redirect to a page you can see only if you are logged in. All good so far.

However I can't manage to actually get users data, what's the best way to get for example the list of properties in a user's account or even better the number of page views a property had in the last week?

This is my code so far:

**/pools/models.py**

```
from django import http
from oauth2client.contrib.django_util import decorators
from django.views.generic import ListView
# from polls.models import GoogleAnalytic
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Google Analytics
from apiclient.discovery import build

# def index(request):
#     return http.HttpResponse("Hello and Welcome! </br> </br> Click <a href='/profile_enabled'> here</a> to login")

@decorators.oauth_required
def get_profile_required(request):
    resp, content = request.oauth.http.request(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me')
    return http.HttpResponse(content)

@decorators.oauth_enabled
def get_profile_optional(request):
    if request.oauth.has_credentials():
        # this could be passed into a view
        # request.oauth.http is also initialized
        return http.HttpResponse('You are signed in.</br> </br>'+'User email: {}'.format(
            request.oauth.credentials.id_token['email']) + "</br></br>Click <a href='/ga'> here </a> to view your metrics")
    else:
        return http.HttpResponse(
            'Hello And Welcome!</br></br>'
            'You need to sign in to view your data. </br></br>' +
            'Here is an OAuth Authorize link:<a href="{}">Authorize</a>'
            .format(request.oauth.get_authorize_redirect()))

########## MY CODE! ###############

@decorators.oauth_required
def google_analytics(object):
    return HttpResponse('These are your results for last week:')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import urls
from polls import views
import oauth2client.contrib.django_util.site as django_util_site


urlpatterns = [
    urls.url(r'^$', views.get_profile_optional),
    urls.url(r'^profile_required$', views.get_profile_required),
    # urls.url(r'^profile_enabled$', views.get_profile_optional),
    urls.url(r'^oauth2/', urls.include(django_util_site.urls)),
    urls.url(r'^ga/$', views.google_analytics)
]
```

**settings.py**

```
  [...]


    GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'

    GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXX'

    GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPES = ('email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics')
```

So my problem is I don't really understand where Django saves the token to access the data of that particular user, I know it works because it prints out the email address correctly etc, but I can't figure out what I should add to `def google_analytics(object):` to actually get specific Google API methods.

If anyone has experience on these kind of things I would really appreciate some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch Google Analytics configuration details e.g. Accounts, Web properties, Profiles, Filters, Goals, etc you can do that using [Google Analytics Management API V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/?hl=en)

If you want to fetch data of certain [dimension and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) from a Google Analytics view (aka profile), you can do that using either [Core Reporting API V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) or [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet).

I think you will find the python api examples in their respective Guides.